# jQuery Tools gallery with thumbnails Need to slide instead of fade

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

I am currently trying to get this image gallery on jQuery tools to switch the sliding gallery instead of fading.

http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/gallery.html

I was curious how I would go about doing that.

```
$(".items img").click(function() {
// see if same thumb is being clicked
if ($(this).hasClass("active")) { return; }

// calclulate large image's URL based on the thumbnail URL (flickr specific)
var url = $(this).attr("src").replace("_t", "");

// get handle to element that wraps the image and make it semi-transparent
var wrap = $("#image_wrap").fadeTo("medium", 0.5);

// the large image from www.flickr.com
var img = new Image();


// call this function after it's loaded
img.onload = function() {

    // make wrapper fully visible
    wrap.fadeTo("fast", 1);

    // change the image
    wrap.find("img").attr("src", url);

};

// begin loading the image from www.flickr.com
img.src = url;

// activate item
$(".items img").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");

// when page loads simulate a "click" on the first image
}).filter(":first").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the following events,

```
 $(<element>).slideIn(); // display image
 $(<element>).slideOut(); //remove image
```

Answer (score 0):

try `var wrap = $("#image_wrap").animate("width", 0);`